# Wordpress style selector?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to know about http://theme-fusion.com/avada/ Style selector.

Visitor is able to change background, layout. etc.

Is there a plugin for this? or some script.

How it is developed to work with wordpress

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ here you can ask this.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128127/wordpress-style-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just 2 CSS stylesheets that can be switched by the user with a bit of JS.

```
$('select').change(function (){
  var newCSS = $(this).val();
  if(newCSS == "style2"){
     $('link[href="style1.css"]').attr('href','style2.css');
  }
  else {
     $('link[href="style2.css"]').attr('href','style1.css');
  }
});
```

You don't need WP plugin to do this.